# Issue resizing ImageView programmatically

Tags: android, android-imageview, image-resizing

I am stuck trying to resize ImageView objects.

The issue is that when I set the width/height programmatically, I see the width/height change with the debugger tool in eclipse.

However, the image will not scale to the new size, and maintains its current ratios. In some cases it even puts the original image at its current size, and moving to a different activity will resize it (somewhat) correctly.

**Screenshots:**

After opening the app
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDWIq.jpg

After opening and closing a different activity
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL73N.jpg

I would like for the images to sit next to each other, with the same width/height for each image.

**onCreate() Method:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_behavior);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.display_behavior_listview);

    List<Behavior> behaviorList = parseCatagories();
    List<View> views = getCatagoryViewsFromBehaviorList(behaviorList);

    // Setup array adapter
    BehaviorRow behaviorRows[] = getBehaviorRows(views);

    int viewCount = 0;
    View view;
    for (BehaviorRow row : behaviorRows) {

        if (viewCount < views.size()) {
            view = views.get(viewCount);
            row.setBehaviorOne(view);
            viewCount++;

            view = views.get(viewCount);
            row.setBehaviorTwo(view);
            viewCount++;
        }

        Log.i("BehaviorRowDat", row.toString());
    }

    BehaviorRowAdapter adapter = new BehaviorRowAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.catagory_row,
            behaviorRows);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

**onWindowFocusChanged() Method:**

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    ImageView catagoryOne;
    ImageView catagoryTwo;

    for (int i = 0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        catagoryOne = (ImageView) listView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.catagory_space_one);
        catagoryTwo = (ImageView) listView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.catagory_space_two);

        resizeImageView(catagoryOne);
        resizeImageView(catagoryTwo);
    }
}
```

**Resize Image Code:**

```
private ImageView resizeImageView(ImageView image) {

    // Set length/width
    int length = calculateLengthOfImages();
    image.getLayoutParams().height = length;
    image.getLayoutParams().width = length;

    // Set Padding
    int padding = calculatePaddingOfImages();
    image.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    return image;
}
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/catagory_row_created"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/catagory_space_one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/catagory_placeholder"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/catagory_space_two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/catagory_placeholder"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Providing a screenshot will be much easier to help.

Comment: @husseinElFeky I added screen shots and tried to describe better what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the scaleType attribute in your ImageViews to:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Alternatively, you can add this line in your resizeImageView() method:

```
image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I wanted the images to scale to the size of the imageview, and then cropCenter. Changing it to fitXY works but stretches the images

Answer (score 0):

**Replace your xml with this:**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/catagory_row_created"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/catagory_space_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/catagory_space_two"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**In onCreate() of your activity, add this:**

```
final ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.catagory_space_one);
final ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.catagory_space_two);

imageView1.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        imageView1.getLayoutParams().height = imageView1.getWidth();
        imageView1.requestLayout();
    }
});

imageView2.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        imageView2.getLayoutParams().height = imageView2.getWidth();
        imageView2.requestLayout();
    }
});
```

So what basically I did is I have stretched the two images' width equally to take the whole space in xml using layout_weight, then I have set the images' height to be like their respective widths in code. So now they are square-shaped.

Hope that helps.

Comment: there is an catagory_space_one & catagory_space_two in each listview child. Putting the code in my on create would not do me any good. I placed the code into my adapter and while some images are square, some are not.

Comment: @AaronEvans Check my updated answer. I added one more line of code to both ImageView. This will recalculate the height of each one. It is a must to write it if you won't write your code in onCreate().

Comment: Unfortunately some images are not scaling up to the desired width and height, and are remaining rectangular.

Comment: Try declaring your image views above onCreate and reference them in onCreate after declaring your listview and have set the adapter for it, then write my answer below that. I believe it should work. I hope.

Comment: Wait a minute, didn't you say that the images are resized correctly after reopening the same activity? Do you have anything in onResume()? Also just try adding **imageView.requestLayout();** after you set their size programmatically from your own solution. This will refresh your imageView. That might work. Try and tell me.

Comment: Yes, I added that yesterday. I am very frustrated because I've been working on a solution to this problem for weeks now and I am getting no where :(